# Why does this shell script fail, if it works when I enter each line into a terminal?

Tags: python, terminal, sh, virtual-environment, beeware

I've made a short **shell script** which goes like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

PROJECT_NAME="my_project"

mkdir $PROJECT_NAME
cd $PROJECT_NAME
python3 -m venv beeware-venv
source beeware-venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install briefcase
briefcase new
```

When I run this script with `sh create_new_beeware_project`, the first line to fail is `source beeware-venv/bin/activate`; the error I get is 'source: not found'. However, **if I enter each line into the terminal one by one, everything works**.

This isn't a big problem in and of itself; ultimately, I can just enter the commands manually. But **it makes me think that there's something important about shell script that I haven't understood**, and if possible I would like to have that explained to me.

Comment: Are you running it from same path ? See the current directory is same in both cases

Comment: Try adding ./beeware-venv/bin/activate

Comment: How do you run your script? It might be important, because there is a typo (it should start with `#!`, you have those chars swapped).

Comment: @VPfB Apologies. That was a typo in my question, but not in my code. I'll change that now.

Comment: @PDHide Where should I insert that line?

Comment: source ./beeware-venv/bin/activate  , assuming you are running script from the terminal path that has beeware-venv

Comment: @PDHide I put in the `./` like you said, but it didn't seem to make any difference. :(

Comment: may be try printing pwd and ls see what is the shell scripts current directory ?

Comment: I've already tried that. If I put a `pwd` just before the `source ...` line, I get '/home/tom/my_project', which I'm fairly sure is what I want. Strangely, the `python3 -m venv beeware-venv` command seems to put the virtual environment in the right place, but, *within the shell script*, the `source ...` command seems unable to find it.

Comment: when you do ls can you see beeware-venv in the list

Comment: Ah, no. So that's the problem. I think I know how to fix this now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227968/discussion-between-tom-hosker-and-pdhide).

Comment: `source` is a non-standard alias for `.`, and isn't recognized by your `/bin/sh`. Use `.` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two shells involved: your interactive shell, which is likely `bash`, and `/bin/sh`, your system's default POSIX shell. `source` is a non-standard alias for `.` which your `/bin/sh` does not recognize. Use `.` instead.

```
#!/bin/sh

PROJECT_NAME="my_project"

mkdir "$PROJECT_NAME" || exit 1
cd "$PROJECT_NAME"
python3 -m venv beeware-venv
. beeware-venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install briefcase
briefcase new
```

Comment: Thank you. At least it wasn't fundamental misunderstanding of the nature of shell script!